# I can not find the prob in my app ;/

Tags: android, android-activity

i Have big problem ! i'm new android developer and when i debug or run my app a blank activity shows up ! nothing more ! i can not understand can u find the problem please ? 
i have no experience and this thing really get me nervous what can i do ?

```
package com.example.calculator;

import android.R.id;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button button;
    Button button2;
    Button button3; 
    EditText text;
    EditText text2;

    double x,y;
    double z=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1) ;
        text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text2) ;

        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);

        x=Double.parseDouble(text.getText().toString());
        y=Double.parseDouble(text2.getText().toString());
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
          switch(v.getId()){

          case R.id.button1: 
                 z=x+y;
               break;

          case R.id.button2: 
                 z=x-y;
               break;

          case R.id.button3: 
              z=x*y;
              break;
          }

          String total = "0";
          total = String.valueOf(z);
          AlertDialog alertDialog;
          alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
          alertDialog.setTitle("Your result");
          alertDialog.setMessage(total);
          alertDialog.show();

    }





}
```

my layout is look like

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@style/AppTheme"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:text="@string/num1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="@string/num2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="0" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="@string/minus" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
        android:text="@string/add" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:text="@string/multiply" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try additionally providing your layout file.

Comment: What's ur R.layout.activity_main xml look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: , so the parsing of string to double should be in the action (onClick)  (Error in parsing null) : this code work perfectly :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    Button button;
    Button button2;
    Button button3; 
    EditText text;
    EditText text2;

    double x=0,y=0;
    double z=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1) ;
        text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text2) ;


        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);



    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //parsing should be here
        x=Double.parseDouble(text.getText().toString());
        y=Double.parseDouble(text2.getText().toString());
          switch(v.getId()){

          case R.id.button1: 
                 z=x+y;
               break;

          case R.id.button2: 
                 z=x-y;
               break;

          case R.id.button3: 
              z=x*y;
              break;
          }

          String total = "0";
          total = String.valueOf(z);
          AlertDialog alertDialog;
          alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
          alertDialog.setTitle("Your result");
          alertDialog.setMessage(total);
          alertDialog.show();

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one activity where one is blank you might be starting your app with that activity is set to be the start up one
I suggest you check your AndroidManefist.xml file

you should see this intent filter with the main (start up) activity

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

make sure its enclosed within your MainActivity declaration in the manifest

```
<activity> ... here ... </activity>
```

if that did'nt help try to fix you project properties and clean the project
(fix : right click on the project folder in eclipse -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties)
(Clean : From the Menu click "Project" -> Clean -> chose your project and click ok)

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just made this change in your code.

```
public void onClick(View v) 
        {
             x=Double.parseDouble(text.getText().toString());
             y=Double.parseDouble(text2.getText().toString());

            switch(v.getId())

            {

              case R.id.button1: 
                     z=x+y;
                   break;

              case R.id.button2: 
                     z=x-y;
                   break;

              case R.id.button3: 
                  z=x*y;
                  break;
              }

              String total = "0";
              total = String.valueOf(z);
              AlertDialog alertDialog;
              alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
              alertDialog.setTitle("Your result");
              alertDialog.setMessage(total);
              alertDialog.show();

        }
```

Note: Make Sure you are Validating your EditText, that is you are entering some number in edittext ,otherwise it will give you NumberFormatException bcoz you are giving "" on click to parse.